# What refreshes Sweeping Wind?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

> Surround yourself in a vortex that continuously deals 15% weapon damage to all enemies within 10 yards. The vortex lasts 6 seconds and **is refreshed each time you strike an enemy with a melee attack**. Landing a Critical Hit has a chance to increase the vortex effect up to 2 times for a total of 44% weapon damage to nearby enemies.

So what counts as a melee attack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested every skill and the following attacks refresh Sweeping Wind.  It should be noted that Sweeping Wind is refreshed **when the skill is used** instead of when the attack hits.

**Normal Attacks**

**All Primary Skills**

- [Fists of Thunder](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/fists-of-thunder)
- [Deadly Reach](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/deadly-reach)
- [Crippling Wave](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/crippling-wave)
- [Way of the Hundred Fists](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/way-of-the-hundred-fists)

**All Secondary Skills**

- [Lashing Tail Kick](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/lashing-tail-kick)
- [Tempest Rush](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/tempest-rush)
- [Wave of Light](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/wave-of-light)

**[Dashing Strike](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/dashing-strike)**

**[Seven-Sided Strike](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/sevensided-strike)**

Finally, using **Sweeping Wind** again will refresh the timer *and* maintain any stacks.

Although Sweeping Wind's description specifies striking an **enemy**, it can both refresh *and* stack (via a crit) when one of the above attacks is used against a destructible piece of the environment. It can, however be difficult to reach the item you want to strike before Sweeping Wind itself destroys it.  Thus, this effect can most easily be seen by using Dashing Strike to charge and hit an item.

Comment: having the teleport with fist of thunder is also good to use for destroying environment

Comment: Deadly Reach is pretty handy to smash barrels and chain.