# Effect of AS on Sweeping Wind

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the most out of Sweeping Wind?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67131/how-can-i-get-the-most-out-of-sweeping-wind)

Does attack speed affect the DPS of Sweeping Wind? When my friend tested, it didn't seem to affect the rate at which the skill ticked (according to him), and I'd like some other input.

Comment: Attack speed does not change the damage rate. Attacking faster may mean you crit more frequently, which may improve Sweeping Wind's uptime though.