# When doesn't Cyclone Strike pull enemies in?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I've noticed that there are times when Cyclone Strike just doesn't do what it's supposed to.  I *thought* it was due to enemies being frozen, but now I have seen some non-frozen enemies unaffected and some frozen enemies affected.  What determines whether or not Cyclone Strike actually pulls enemies in?

Comment: My guess based on using it is there is a hard cap on the number of monsters it will pull in.  I think it's roughly 8 but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have observed this with only 1 monster.

Comment: Is it any particular enemy? Some are immune to being pulled around by Cyclone strike, usually larger ones, champions, or the treasure goblin at later difficulty levels.

Comment: @Rachel sounds like the beginning of an answer...

Answer (score 2):

Some enemies are immune to being dragged around by Cyclone Strike

The ones I know of are

- Some larger enemies, such as Demonic Tremors
- All Act bosses and some smaller Bosses
- Some champions, typically larger ones
- Treasure Goblins at higher difficulty levels